# Mongo DB update operation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Below query wrongly update by mongoDB

Query:

```
d.update({'Objects.out.interface': 'down', 'IP': '192.168.106.11', 'INID': 19, 'SESSION': 1, 'Objects.id': 4}, {$set: {'Objects.$.score':888888}})
```

Why my score 888888 updated in Objects.id:2 not in  Objects.id:4 ?

Update result:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59b7ebec9315080ac2801468"),
        "SESSION" : 1,
        "INID" : 19,
        "IP" : "192.168.106.11",
        "Hostname" : "Npppp",
        "JOBNAME" : "Nexus2-12-September-19-45-08",
        "Authentication" : "{\"username\":\"gowtham\",\"password\":\"pppppp\"}",
        "Objects" : [
                {
                        "name" : "self",
                        "out" : {
                                "status" : "reachable"
                        },
                        "type" : "self_check",
                        "id" : 1,
                        "rank" : [
                                {
                                        "regex" : {
                                                "status" : "down"
                                        },
                                        "score" : 0
                                },
                                {
                                        "regex" : {
                                                "status" : "reachable"
                                        },
                                        "score" : 100
                                }
                        ],
                        "monitor" : "self",
                        "score" : 100
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Eth1/1",
                        "out" : {
                                "interface" : "down"
                        },
                        "type" : "cis_sw_int",
                        "id" : 2,
                        "rank" : [
                                {
                                        "regex" : {
                                                "interface" : "down"
                                        },
                                        "score" : 0
                                },
                                {
                                        "regex" : {
                                                "interface" : "up"
                                        },
                                        "score" : 100
                                }
                        ],
                        "monitor" : "bits,duplex,speed,error",
                        "score" : 888888
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Eth1/37",
                        "out" : {
                                "interface" : "down"
                        },
                        "type" : "cis_sw_int",
                        "id" : 3,
                        "rank" : [
                                {
                                        "regex" : {
                                                "interface" : "down"
                                        },
                                        "score" : 0
                                },
                                {
                                        "regex" : {
                                                "interface" : "up"
                                        },
                                        "score" : 100
                                }
                        ],
                        "monitor" : "bits,duplex,speed,error"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Eth1/46",
                        "out" : {
                                "interface" : "down"
                        },
                        "type" : "cis_sw_int",
                        "id" : 4,
                        "rank" : [
                                {
                                        "regex" : {
                                                "interface" : "down"
                                        },
                                        "score" : 0
                                },
                                {
                                        "regex" : {
                                                "interface" : "up"
                                        },
                                        "score" : 100
                                }
                        ],
                        "monitor" : "bits,duplex,speed,error"
                }
        ],
        "timeout" : 10,
        "TD" : ISODate("2017-09-12T19:45:08.743Z")
}
```

Comment: Try without `'Objects.out.interface': 'down'`. What is the result?

Comment: same results because both objects are having 'down'

Comment: @user3041095, that's not true. If you remove `'Objects.out.interface': 'down'` it updates the one with id:4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have 2 conditions for subdocuments:

```
'Objects.out.interface': 'down', 
'Objects.id': 4
```

[Positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) uses first matching sub-document

> the positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches the query document,

In your case the first match for `'Objects.out.interface': 'down'` is the one with id:2.

You need to change the filter to use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) to use both conditions to identify the subdocument:

```
{
    'IP': '192.168.106.11', 
    'INID': 19, 
    'SESSION': 1, 
    'Objects': {
        $elemMatch: {
            'out.interface': 'down', 
            'id': 4
        }
    }
}
```